# How to scrape a dynamic webpage using puppeteer-core in a deployed application?

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to build an application that scrapes a dynamic webpage with the node module "puppeteer-core". The idea is to make the user click a button that will trigger a function. This function will scrape the content and return it to the user.

I set up webpack (correctly, I think), but when I build the project for production, webpack is not capable to bundle "puppeteer-core". I have the following error:

"Can't resolve 'ws' module in 'path/to/node_module/puppeteer-core/lib" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ht8j.png)

Why am I having this error and how to solve it? It's possible to scrape a dynamic webpage in a deployed application (not using server-side nodejs)?

Webpack version: 4.28.2

I tried to use "webpack-node-externals" but with no success.

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require("path")
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './Client/js/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{ loader: "babel-loader"}]
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

I would like the achieve what I mentioned above. Allow the user to:

Click the button > Scrape Dynamic Website > Return the Information

Comment: Puppeteer won't run from a browser. It's a "server-side" library.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, pguardiano. Is there a way to scrape a dynamic webpage from client side? I do not know if it is possible.

Comment: Probably not from a regular browser because of CORS.